# How to use 'AND' when printing a report with multiple parameters?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Does there need to be parenthesis anywhere for the 'AND' to work?

Both SpecialistSearch and SupplierSearch are unbound comboboxes. These do work individually for the report.

When I add 'AND', the report fails.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Order Report", acPreview, , "[Specialist]=" & Chr(34) & Me!SpecialistSearch & Chr(34) And "[Supplier]=" & Chr(34) & Me!SupplierSearch & Chr(34)
```

I receive an error.

> Type Mismatch

But doesn't show me what is wrong.

Comment: Try moving the "And" inside the parenthesis like this `"And [Supplier]="`.

Comment: Thank you @BrianMStafford this worked! It's always so difficult with all these quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most correct way, imo, is to use parameters.

```
DoCmd.SetParameter "pSpecialist", Me!SpecialistSearch.Value
DoCmd.SetParameter "pSupplier", Me!SupplierSearch.Value
DoCmd.OpenReport "Order Report", acPreview, , "[Specialist] = pSpecialist And [Supplier]=pSupplier"
```

Alternately, you could construct a valid SQL statement, which means in quotes AND with a leading space in quotes.

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "Order Report", acPreview, , "[Specialist]=" & Chr(34) & Me!SpecialistSearch & Chr(34) " And [Supplier]=" & Chr(34) & Me!SupplierSearch & Chr(34)
```

This second option opens you up to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which might seem minor because for Access databases, we usually fully trust the user, but it can also lead to annoying bugs, for example, if your supplier is *Jack "The Giant" Chairs*, that'd cause the SQL statement to break and the application to malfunction.

Comment: Great best practice answer in MS Access! I always tend to forget `SetParameter`.

Comment: Follow up question: How would I use "AND" and "OR" in this statement? What if the user only wants either the supplier or specialist? I've noticed my report won't load if only one is chosen.

Comment: @SharonIsKaren I'm not sure I understand you. If you want the field to not matter when it's empty, you can try `([Specialist] = pSpecialist OR pSpecialist & '' = '') AND   [Supplier]=pSupplier OR pSupplier & '' = '')` in your `WHERE` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, consider using a saved query that points directly to form controls. Then, update or use this query as report's record source in VBA. Do note: form needs to be opened (but not the query) for form controls to be read as parameters. This avoids need of any quotes or ampersands.

**SQL** *(adjust `myForm` name)*

```sql
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
FROM myTable
WHERE [Specialist] = Forms!myForm!SpecialistSearch 
  AND [Supplier] = Forms!myForm!SupplierSearch
```

**VBA**

*Using above named query as recordsource*

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "Open Report", acPreview
```

*Updating recordsource to above named query*

```vb
DoCmd.OpenReport "Order Report", acViewReport                     ' OPEN IN REPORT VIEW
Reports("Order Report").Report.RecordSource = "mySavedQuery"      ' ADJUST RECORDSOURCE

DoCmd.OpenReport "Open Report", acPreview                         ' OPEN IN PREVIEW MODE
```